# Feature doesn't display on map using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, vector, python-2.7

I want to create a layer using PyQGIS, then draw a point in a specific place on a map and add some data to the attribute table. Everything went fine, the script below works but no point seems to be displayed on a map canvas. 
 The code below is from the PuQGIS Developer Cookbook (http://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#id8) but nonetheless the point is not visible.

What can be the ploblem?

```
 def create_layer(self, point, values):
    vl = QgsVectorLayer("Point", "Temporary point layer", "memory")
    pr = vl.dataProvider()

    vl.startEditing()

    pr.addAttributes( [ QgsField("ID", QVariant.Int),
                        QgsField("R",  QVariant.Int),
                        QgsField("G", QVariant.Int),
                        QgsField("B", QVariant.Int),
                        QgsField("Class", QVariant.String)] )
    vl.updateFields()

    feat = QgsFeature()
    feat.setGeometry( QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(500253, 8180778)))
    feat.setAttributes([0, int(values[0]), int(values[1]), int(values[2])])
    pr.addFeatures([feat])

    vl.updateExtents()
    vl.commitChanges()
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
    layer = iface.setActiveLayer(vl)
    if not layer:
        self.dlg.l_status.setText("Error: Layer failed to load!")
    else:
        QgsMapCanvas().setLayerSet( [ QgsMapCanvasLayer(vl) ] )
        iface.zoomToActiveLayer()
```

Here is a screenshot. I zoomed to a temporary layer with a point.

[image]

Comment: Your code seems ok... Maybe is it related to the crs? You didn't specify it when creating the memory layer.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. It worked. I write a plugin and implemented this piece of code there to manually select CRS but it seems to be working not as I thought.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to hint from @mgri, I found the solution. It was all about CRS. I had to specify CRS programmatically while creating a temporary layer so instead of

```
vl = QgsVectorLayer("Point", "Temporary point layer", "memory")
```

I used

```
vl = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=epsg:32645", "Temporary point layer", "memory")
```

And now everything works fine.

Comment: Well done! You wrote a good code, though. +1